# Select query from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I think everything is good then why data is not shown in textboxes. I used this code a lot of times. Then what's error here? I am working in Visual Studio 2012.

```
string name = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

query = "select *from Record Where Name='"+name+"'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
     textBox1.Text =(dr["Items1"].ToString());
     textBox2.Text = (dr["Items1_Charge"].ToString());
     textBox3.Text = (dr["Items2"].ToString());
     textBox4.Text = (dr["Items2_Charge"].ToString());
     textBox5.Text = (dr["Items3"].ToString());
     textBox6.Text = (dr["Items3_Charge"].ToString());
     textBox7.Text = (dr["Items4"].ToString());
     textBox8.Text = (dr["Items4_Charge"].ToString());               
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line? Did you debug your code? You need a space by the way in your `*from` part as `* from`.

Comment: Oh no, do NOT concatenate string queries. Train yourself to use [parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: also, why use a while loop to set same control? Assuming you expect your query to return just one record, just call once `dr.Read()`

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect *from should be * from. Also I would suggest using parameters for the where condition as shown below especially when there is a chance of an embedded apostrophe. Also note I added HasRows so we are sure something came back. I also change how you are getting the current value from the ComboBox

```
public void Sample()
{
    string name = comboBox1.Text;
    query = "select * from Record Where Name= @Name";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = (dr["Items1"].ToString());
            textBox2.Text = (dr["Items1_Charge"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (dr["Items2"].ToString());
            textBox4.Text = (dr["Items2_Charge"].ToString());
            textBox5.Text = (dr["Items3"].ToString());
            textBox6.Text = (dr["Items3_Charge"].ToString());
            textBox7.Text = (dr["Items4"].ToString());
            textBox8.Text = (dr["Items4_Charge"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```